# PowerMockito: Unfinished stubbing detected (Unfinished Stubbing Exception)

Tags: java, junit, powermockito

Logic

```
public class Logic {
String date = (LocalDateTime.now()).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
}
```

Mock Code

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ LocalDateTime.class })
public class LogicTest {

@InjectMocks
Logic target = new Logic();

PowerMockito.mockStatic(LocalDateTime.class);
when(LocalDateTime.now()).thenReturn(LocalDateTime.of(2017, 8, 24, 8, 50, 9));

}
```

When I am trying to write the jUnit test case for the above function, an exception "UnfinishedStubbingException" is shown.

I read other answers, but even after that, I am unable to understand the reason for the error.

Comment: Could you try to store the value of `LocalDateTime.of(2017, 8, 24, 8, 50, 9)` in an intermediate variable, and pass that variable as the `thenReturn` parameter ?

Comment: there is no method around `when(...`

Comment: @Berger It Worked !
Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are running the method `LocalDateTime.of(2017, 8, 24, 8, 50, 9)` after you have informed PowerMockito that `LocalDateTime` static methods should be mocked.  So PowerMockito is trying to operate on mocked methods, while in the middle of a stubbing call.  You can't call one mocked method while you're in the middle of mocking another.

The correct way to do this kind of thing is not to mock `LocalDateTime`, but to mock `Clock`.  Your `Logic` class should have an instance of `Clock` that you can inject, and you can then use `LocalDateTime.now(theClock)` instead of `LocalDateTime.now()`.  This makes the `Logic` class much more testable, because you can then inject your mock `Clock`.

You don't actually need PowerMockito for this - ordinary Mockito will do just fine.